# Dehydration immediate signs

Tags: health

I've noticed i get palpitations and uncomfortable chest pain after taking my coffee. As advised under my previous post to limit my intake, ive started doing that subtracting a whopping 100mg of caffiene. (So my average everyday is 300mg). The rampant jitters have subsided but i still feel palpitations and sore pain in my chest and the only thing that sort of calms it down is chewing on a cloth. I only notice this after I am unfocused and have completed the work i chugged the coffee down for. I put 2 and 2 together and obviously i am dehydrated. But i've never experienced this before my body usually has that normal thirst and thats my call to drink water. I still drink water obviously but only with meals or after something strenous. The palpitations dont necessarily tickle my brain into feeling thirsty....

So i guess my question is can I make myself crave more water naturally on days i am drinking coffee..to avoid the uncomfortable events or do i have to make it part of a rigorous routine..?
Or am i just being paranoid?

EDIT: Just checked my blood pressure its 73/48....im off to the doctors

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this site is about coffee. We can not and do not give health advice.